# How to display saved SQL queries in a window within Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Many years ago someone showed me that you can display or save your SQL queries in a window within Oracle SQL Developer.

I forget how to make that happen? Does anyone know how or what it is called? Under View menu?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean [a SQL Worksheet](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/01/a-sql-developer-primer-open-a-new-worksheet/)?

Comment: No. It looks like a small window that displays all the queries you have built. If you want to run one of them, you can double click it, then it will run. That is what I remembered.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

It is called Snippets in View menu.

You can create your query there and just use it from there too.

Thank you all!

Comment: Sure you can put queries there. Or you could put them in reports. Or SQL code templates.